# How can I write well-structured ideas without overusing connectors such as "moreover" and "in addition to"

Tags: structure

When I write, I find some obstacles in forming well-structured ideas and my writing does not sound natural because of overusing connectors.
How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Could you [edit] in some examples of the problem?  By "connectors" do you mean transition words like "however", conjunctions like "and", or something else?  Also, what type of writing?  (Fiction, blog posts, academic papers, technical documentation...)

Comment: yes , by connectors i mean words  like moreover , in addition , and furthermore etc ..... The type of writing is acedemic

Comment: Perhaps you are using such connectors just to make yourself comfortable. Try separate, simple sentences - no connectors, to start with.

Comment: In my experience, using those words is characteristic of academic writing. It sounds unnatural because the style of academic writing is to sound unnatural. It only becomes a problem when you're writing a romance novel and your heroine pronounces to her best friend, "I broke up with Bob because, in addition to his emotional unavailability, he cheated on me with his secretary. Moreover, his mustache was visibly soiled."

Answer (score 1):

You can vary your sentence structure to include other common constructions.

Your basic structure is *Idea1; adverb, idea2.* Because of your propensity for this construction, I wouldn't suggest, but certainly could do, *Idea1. Adverb clause, idea2.*

Some options:

The reactive agent was **not only** stable in its pH **but** did not increase the molality of the solution.

In conclusion, **either** the left kidney receivers more blood flow in comparison to the right **or** the receptors on the left kidney are more sensitive to local growth factors.

**If** the rat brain's endogenous opiate system is activated, **then** we see increased amounts of endomorphin 1 in its bloodstream.

Cosmic radiation is necessary for the phenomenon known as *Northern Lights* **because** it creates cosmic dust in the atmosphere, **and** it excites the molecules into the visible spectrum in scintillating patterns.

Answer (score 1):

"moreover" and "in addition to" are the kind of connectors that occur to us when we think of another idea as we are writing. It often happens that as you are writing one idea in support of a point, another one pops into your head, and then another one. In the urgency to get them down before they fly our of you head, you end up tacking them onto your existing paragraph or sentence structure with connectors.

That is fine for making sure that you record these points before you loose them. But now you have a paragraph structure that was designed to support one point that in now supporting three points strung together with connectors. The way you fix this is to re-architect the paragraph to support three points.

This could be as simple as beginning:

> Blah blah blah for each of the following reasons:
>
> 1. Blah
> 2. Blah blah
> 3. Blather blather blather

In other words, the solution is to go back and create the structure you would have created in the first place if you had realized you were going to have this many points to make when you started.